# Running twice the libraries to have interactive plots on jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Every time I want to have an interactive plot on Jupyter,  I have to run the libraries twice. The libraries are as simple as this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
```

The first time I make a plot I have a static image (like shown here). If I run again the libraries, the figure is now interactive. Do you know why?

Static image: 
[image]

Interactive image:
[image]

Comment: You need to put `%matplotlib notebook` before importing `pyplot`

Comment: What do you mean by run the libraries?

Comment: shift-enter twice. DavidG, you solved the problem of 5 people in the same office!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the backend before importing `pyplot`. Therefore the order of your command matters. You will need to put any `%matplotlib ...` command before importing `pyplot`:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```